# Why does Linux crash when I put my Thinkpad into sleeping mode?

Tags: kernel, suspend, crash, thinkpad

I am using Linux Mint 20.1 on a Thinkpad T14(AMD).
Every time I close the lid or let the laptop go into suspension mode due to idleness, the screen turns black and the computer doesn't react anymore until I shut it down.

My software manager showed me supported possible Kernel updates until 5.13.40. I tried updating to unsupported Kernel versions 5.15.x anthed the issue seems to dissapear, however then I get Wifi problems so I rolled back to the 5.13.30 Linux Kernel.

Does anybody have an idea how I could fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!